# Google Nearby notification API not showing new notifications

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

This is my first post here so please excuse my mistakes.

I am trying to work with Nearby notification. I have added the beacon via "beacon tools" and from my dashboard have added nearby notification. As you can see in the picture, the new notifications are appended at the bottom.

[Nearby notification dashboard_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36hKF.jpg)

So in this case, "**Title #3**" is the latest and that's the one I see in Nearby app when I am next to beacon.

Now, when I tried adding Nearby notifications to my beacons via Proximity API.
I have added the beacon to my project, and I am using

```
gapi.client.request
```

to add an attachment to my beacon, using the Proximity beacon API. The add attachment URI:

```
https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons/(BeaconName)/attachments
```

I am formatting the attachment as such

```
  {
  "title": "Example",
  "url": "https://www.example.com"
}
```

When I added 3 notifications via this (one at a time of course), they do show up in my google dashboard for that beacon. But the new ones are stacked on the top, instead of appending at bottom(as seen in the second pic)

[Nearby notification dashboard_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36hKF.jpg)

So as you could guess, only the first added notification is visible via Nearby, i.e "**Title #1**"

Am I missing something here? How do I make the new notifications appear using Proximity API?

PS: I am using Eddystone UID for this.

Comment: Good question about the inconsistency, but couldn't you just delete the old notifications and only have one?

Comment: Yes that's the solution I have currently implemented. But that becomes a problem when I add targeting. You see, for targeting you tend to create multiple notification entries. So targeting would be impossible to achieve with current solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

It seems this was a bug and I had been trying to contact Google in several ways. Finally it reached them and they fixed it today :)

So latest notifications are now automatically displayed & targeting works well.

Kudos to Google engineers working on Nearby!

Comment: Can you please mention what was the bug

Comment: Oh the inconsistency was the bug. When you push a new message via the API, it didn't show up on nearby notifications. The only way to show it up was if you deleted the previous message from the stack.
Thus it was impossible to have time targeted messages via the API